# Generate an array of bit vectors with no repeated columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of dimensions `[batch_size, input_dim]` which needs to be filled only with `0` or `1`. I need element in each column to be distinct from the rest of the columns. I have taken a approach like below:

```py
 train_data = np.zeros(shape=[batch, input_dim])
 num_of_ones = random.sample(range(input_dim + 1), batch)
 for k in range(batch):
     num_of_one = num_of_ones[k]
     for _ in range(num_of_one):
         train_data[k][np.random.randint(0, input_dim)] = 1
```

Though this guarantees that no element is repeated (owing to the fact that each column has different number of `1`'s), there are still many combinations that are left out. For instance when `num_of_one = 1`, there are `input_dim` number of possibilities and so on. another downside of the method I have follwed is that both `batch_size` and `input_dim` have to be the same (else `random.sample` throws an error). I do not want to list down all possibilities as that would take forever to complete.

Is there any simple way to achieve the above stated problem?

Comment: I don't think your code does what you think it does. Have you actually tested this? You get different number of ones in each column, compared to `num_of_ones`.

Comment: hi @tituszban, `random.sample` is from the package `random` and it returns unique integers from `[0, input_dim]` and yes I have tested this

Comment: I see "This is not a duplicate of any question" as a challenge. The assumption that no one has asked your question before is more likely to be false than true, statistically speaking. I don't recommend putting it in your question as it serves no purpose.

Comment: Random.sample works just fine. But the way you populate it is wrong. Because you can (and do) get repeating values. So you're testing was wrong.

Comment: @tituszban, I'm sorry there was a formatting issue, does that clear?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I fully agree with you, but it is just to ward off people who hastily report duplicate.

Comment: @learner. It does the opposite of warding. If you start a question defending the fact that your question is good instead of showing me, I automatically assume that's because it doesn't stand on its own. That being said, I enjoyed the problem. I hope you enjoy my answer as well.

Comment: By the way, you generally don't want to index numpy arrays as `a[x][y]`. It doesn't work the same as with lists. Use `a[x, y]` instead.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks. Thank you also for pointing out the indexing notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the binary representation of the numbers from `0` to `7`:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Each row is different! So, all we have to do is convert each row to column. e.g.

```
arr = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
]
```

---

Also, observe that we have used all the unique possibilities. Now, with `3` rows, we can not add `2**3 + 1` th column.

**In general, if `cols > 2**rows`, then we can not find unique representation.**

---

You can do something like this:

```
rows = 3
cols = 8

if 2**rows < cols:
    print('Not possible')

arr = [[None] * cols for _ in range(rows)]

for col_idx in range(cols):
    binary = bin(col_idx)[2:]
    binary = binary.zfill(rows)

    for row_idx in range(rows):
        arr[row_idx][col_idx] = int(binary[row_idx])

for row in arr:
    print(row)
```

Time Complexity: `O(rows * cols)`

Space Complexity: `O(rows * cols)`

Comment: hi dipen, thanks for your answer. But your way of doing it enumerates all possible combinations. My dimension is of the order of `32` and I definitely don't want to list all `2^32`

Comment: Please can you tell the maximum value of rows and cols?

Comment: Actually, I am not asking about my code. Please share your constraints. Then I will explain how it will work perfectly.

Comment: i need 32 length vectors. How many of them I need is a parameter which I specify through the parameter `batch`

Comment: Yes, so it will be 32 * batch, and not 32 * (2**32). Git it? Or is there any confusion?

Comment: one last question, the array that is generated has string values not integers. Any particular reason? Thanks for the wonderful answer.

Comment: No particular reason, it is just because `bin(val)` returns a string. Should I update the answer?

Comment: i guess since I ask for an int array you can add `int()` to the code just so it is complete. Thanks again

Comment: Updated! Please check!

Answer (score 1):

You could select a set of distinct numbers (look in `itertools`) between 0 and 2^`input_dim`, and use their binary representations to get the sequence of 0's and 1's for each value. Since the numbers selected would be distinct, their binary representations would be distinct as well.

Comment: Why `itertools`?

Answer (score 1):

### Why yours doesn't work

Yours has an issue with this line:

```
    for _ in range(num_of_one):
        train_data[k][np.random.randint(0, input_dim)] = 1
```

Because you select random rows to be set to 1, you could have these repeating, and it's not guaranteed that you'll have the right number of ones in each column, hence you can have duplicates. This is essentially no better, than randomizing the entire array, and hoping there are no duplicates.

### Solution

You can achieve this via the magic of binary counting. Each of these columns are a different numbers binary representation. There are some limitations to this, as you would with any solution, where it's impossible to have all unique columns.

```
d = np.arange(input_dim)
random.shuffle(d)
train_data = (((d[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(batch)))) > 0).astype(float).T
print( train_data )
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I realise the mistake in my code. Thanks for pointing it out. Your solution doesn't work as advertised. I set `input_dim=5` and `batch=10` and except for the first three rows (which are distinct) all the others are zeros.

Comment: You aren't converting numbers to binary

Comment: I am. It's the messy third line. Try running it and see for yourself. If you take out the shuffle it's more obvious. And this one isn't limited to uint8 like `np.unpackbits`

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is something like [`np.unpackbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) combined with python's [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). `random.sample` will sample without replacement without creating a list of the input. This means that you can use a `range` object over arbitrarily large integers without any risk of problems, as long as the sample size fits in memory. `np.unpackbits` then converts the integers into unique bit sequences. This idea is a concrete implementation of [@ScottHunter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58286055/2988730).

```
batch_size = number_of_bits
input_size = number_of_samples
```

First, decide how many bytes you'll need to generate, and the max integer that you'll need to cover the range. Remember, Python supports arbitrary precision integers, so go crazy:

```
bytes_size = np.ceil(batch_size / 8)
max_int = 1<<batch_size
```

Now get your unique samples:

```
samples = random.sample(range(max_int), input_size)
```

Python integers are full blown objects with a [`to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method that will prep your samples for `np.unpackbits`:

```
data = np.array([list(x.to_bytes(bytes_size, 'little')) for x in samples], dtype=np.uint8).T
```

The byte order matters if `batch_size` is not a multiple of 8: were going to trim the final array to size.

Now unpack and you're good to go:

```
result = np.unpackbits(data, axis=0)[:batch, :]
```

Putting it all together into a single package:

```
def random_bit_columns(batch_size, input_size):
    samples = random.sample(range(1 << batch_size), input_size)
    data = np.array([list(x.to_bytes(np.ceil(batch_size / 8), 'little')) for x in samples], dtype=np.uint8).T
    result = np.unpackbits(data, axis=0)[:batch, :]
    return result
```

I'm afraid I can't see a way out of using a list comprehension over the number of columns if you want to have the benefit of python's arbitrary precision integers.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have a few comments. What is `batch` in the penaultimate line? Do you mean `batch_size`? Also for some reason, when I ran the code, the compiler was satisfied only when I used `int(np.ceil(batch_size/8))`.